# Enter key pressed event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, textbox, maskedtextbox

I want to capture the text from the textbox when enter key is hit.  I am using WPF/visual studio 2010/.NET 4.  I dont know what event handler to be used in the  tag ?  I also want to do the same for maskedtextbox.

Comment: Can you show us what have you done so far?

Comment: <telerik:RadMaskedTextBox x:Name="maskedtxtbox" Mask="###-##-####"   
KeyDown="txtboxSSN_KeyDown" />

Comment: private void maskedtxtbox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SystemKey == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
            {  //do something here

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Either KeyDown or KeyUp.

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(tb_KeyDown);

static void tb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        //enter key is down
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i do it for the maskedtextbox? its a radmaskedtextbox

Comment: the radmaskedtextbox does not givee an option of "AcceptsReturn" inside the tag..

Comment: Nothing would be different. MaskedTextBox has the same eventhandlers. In fact all controls have them.

Comment: this handler however gets fired when any key sis pressed. I want to fire the event only when enter is pressed. and then I want to collect whats in the textbox. so here is what it does. the user types in a name and presses enter. thats when i want to fire the event. and not while the user is typing his name..i hope this explains it..

Comment: You are right. That's why in the example I gave, there is an if statement checking that condition in the handler method. This is how KeyEventHandlers are designed to work. Unfortunately there is no easy way to do what you want, I do not know if there is any.

Comment: @weberc2 `KeyPress` does not expose the `KeyCode` property.

Comment: very inefficient solution as handler runs with every key pressed. So if a user enters a string of 200 characters and presses enter key in the end, handler runs for 201 times when it should actually run for only 1 time. Your thoughts are welcome on it.

Comment: (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) when i use this shows error.instead (e.Key == Key.Enter) .

Answer (score 23):

You can also use PreviewKeyDown in WPF:

```
<TextBox PreviewKeyDown="EnterClicked" />
```

or in C#:

```
myTextBox.PreviewKeyDown += EnterClicked;
```

And then in the attached class:

```
void EnterClicked(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Key == Key.Return) {
        DoSomething();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The KeyDown event only triggered at the standard TextBox or MaskedTextBox by "normal" input keys, not ENTER or TAB and so on.

One can get special keys like ENTER by overriding the IsInputKey method:

```
public class CustomTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{
    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Return)
            return true;
        return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
    }
}
```

Then one can use the KeyDown event in the following way:

```
CustomTextBox ctb = new CustomTextBox();
ctb.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(tb_KeyDown);

private void tb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
          //Enter key is down

          //Capture the text
          if (sender is TextBox)
          {
              TextBox txb = (TextBox)sender;
              MessageBox.Show(txb.Text);
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In WPF, TextBox element will not get opportunity to use "Enter" button for creating KeyUp Event until you will not set property: AcceptsReturn="True".

But, it would`t solve the problem with handling KeyUp Event in TextBox element. After pressing "ENTER" you will get a new text line in TextBox.

I had solved problem of using KeyUp Event of TextBox element by using Bubble event strategy. It's short and easy. You have to attach a KeyUp Event handler in some (any) parent element:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TextBox_EnterButtomEvent.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextBox_EnterButtomEvent"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid KeyUp="Grid_KeyUp">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height ="0.3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Padding="0" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
        Input text end press ENTER:
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Padding="0" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
        You have entered:
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Name="txtBlock" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid></Window>
```

C# logical part (KeyUp Event handler is attached to a grid element):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Grid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            TextBox txtBox = e.Source as TextBox;
            if(txtBox != null)
            {
                this.txtBlock.Text = txtBox.Text;
                this.txtBlock.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Image with result]

Answer (score 1):

For those who struggle at capturing Enter key on TextBox or other input control, if your Form has AcceptButton defined, you will not be able to use KeyDown event to capture Enter.

What you should do is to catch the Enter key at form level. Add this code to the form:

```cs
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if ((this.ActiveControl == myTextBox) && (keyData == Keys.Return))
    {
        //do something
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```